# Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have downloaded a project from the following link.

https://github.com/DFTinc/onyx-enroll-wizard-sample-app1/tree/master/onyxenrollwizardsampleapp/src/main

Gradle Build is giving the following error.

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':onyxenrollwizardsampleapp:processDebugResources'.
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Android\sdk\build-tools\22.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Moreover, every `R.xxx` function is giving error on **R** as `"cannot resolve symbol R"`

Comment: did you added the dependency??

Comment: No. How can I? Kindly elaborate. I am new to android.

Comment: did you downloaded the project from below link https://github.com/DFTinc/onyx-enroll-wizard-sample-app1 ??

Comment: The "cannot resolve symbol R" appears because your project is not built and R files are not generated yet.

Comment: They are not generating by themselves. I tried that as well.

Comment: @Aashvi yes I did it from that link

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah Make a new project and copy paste class & xml that will be a better option

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah after that you make changes in string file?

Comment: @Aashvi yes. I putted up a key given by the developers

Comment: Create a new project, copy the java files and the resources, add the dependencies to your build.gradle